# Accessing OpenCV Mat element in Java

Tags: java, python

I would like to know Java Equivalent for Python numpy matrix given below.

output = matrix[0][0, :, :]

matrix looks like this

`[ [ [ [  0.06240631  0.05016533  0.04039866  0.05481339]

   [  0.05615342  0.0268873   0.02446797  0.02856365]

   [  0.04960712  0.02596745  0.01981818  0.02116911]

   [  0.06562919  0.03579292  0.02395858  0.02714126] ] ] ]`

and output looks like this

`[ [ 0.06240631  0.05016533  0.04039866  0.05481339]

 [ 0.05615342  0.0268873   0.02446797  0.02856365]

 [ 0.04960712  0.02596745  0.01981818  0.02116911]

 [ 0.06562919  0.03579292  0.02395858  0.02714126] ]`

can anyone guide me in right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the data you reported:

- matrix is a 4 dimensions array
- output is a 2 dimensions array

Taken in consideration these assumptions, this is what should be the corresponding in Java (using curly brackets to init the matrix array):

```
double[][][][] matrix = {{{{0.06240631, 0.05016533, 0.04039866, 0.05481339},

            {0.05615342, 0.0268873, 0.02446797, 0.02856365},

            {0.04960712, 0.02596745, 0.01981818, 0.02116911},

            {0.06562919, 0.03579292, 0.02395858, 0.02714126}}}};    

double[][] output = matrix[0][0];
```

To test `output`, you can print it out using the following line:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(output));
```